# How to add label control programmatically to devexpress xtrareport detail band

Tags: .net, vb.net, devexpress, xtrareport

I have few records from database and I want to add it the programmatically to the detail band of the report. The reason why I am doing this is because there is a dynamic data that needs to be pulled from other table.

I have tried to put the code in the `Detail.BeforePrint` Event, however the second record will consist a record from the first, third record will contain a 1st,2nd record as well and so on.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
Dim _BiayaMeal As Integer = GetCurrentColumnValue("biaya_meal")
Dim _XrLabel As XRLabel = New XRLabel
_XrLabel.Text = _BiayaMeal 
_XrLabel.LocationF = New PointF(_LabelPointX, _LabelPointY)
_XrLabel.SizeF = New Size(100, 23)
_XrLabel.Font = New Font("tahoma", 8)
_XrLabel.TextAlignment = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.TextAlignment.MiddleLeft
_XrLabel.CanGrow = False
Me.Detail.Controls.Add(_XrLabel)
```

Comment: Can you provide visual indications what you're trying to achieve and what you're currently have? [This article](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/AK15900/how-to-create-a-report-dynamically) may helpful for creating report elements dynamically.

Comment: I see that you add a new XRLabel each time the DetailBand.BeforePrint event is called. It's better to add a label at the beginning and then update its text only, on the subsequent event calls. Use the DetailBand.Controls to find a label at runtime. 
However, by this code, I see that in fact a label is bound to "biaya_meal" column, so you can just bind it to this column as described [in this tutorial](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/2556/Detailed-Guide-to-DevExpress-Reporting/Providing-Data-to-Reports/Tutorials-and-Code-Examples/Bind-a-Report-to-an-Array-List-Runtime-Sample)